# Navigation not working in SwiftUI - Pop to a specific view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, navigation

I am trying to pop to a specific view using the `isActive` binding of `NavigationLink` of SwiftUI. Here is my code:

```
struct Root: View
{
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismissValue: DismissAction
    @State var rootToView1Navigattion: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            NavigationLink(isActive: $rootToView1Navigattion) {
                View1()
            } label: {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button {
                dismissValue()
            } label: {
                Text("Go Back")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }

            Button {
                rootToView1Navigattion = true
            } label: {
                Text("Go Forward")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
    }
}

struct View1: View
{
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismissValue: DismissAction
    @State var view1ToView2Navigation: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            NavigationLink(isActive: $view1ToView2Navigation) {
                View2(view1ToView2NavBinding: $view1ToView2Navigation)
            } label: {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            Button {
                dismissValue()
            } label: {
                Text("Go Back")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }

            Button {
                view1ToView2Navigation = true
            } label: {
                Text("Go Forward")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
    }
}

struct View2: View
{
    @Binding var view1ToView2NavBinding: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            Button {
                view1ToView2NavBinding = false
            } label: {
                Text("Go Back")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
    }
}
```

As per my concept, `View1` has a property `view1ToView2Navigation`, which is passed to `isActive` param of `NavigationLink`. And this property is passed as binding to `View2`. When I set it false in `View2`, everything above `View1` should dismiss. But this is not working, Am I missing out something conceptually ??

My RootView is enclosed in a `NavigationView`. And When I do the same between `Root` and `View1`. It works smoothly.

Comment: NavigationView is not capable to do that, use NavigatoinStack (iOS 16+) or some custom solution.

Comment: @Asperi then how come this works between Root and View1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Based on your new comment, you want to navigate back to root from view 2.

Try the below code. When you press the yellow back button in view2, you will be navigated back to root.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismissValue: DismissAction
@State var toRoot = false
var body: some View
{
NavigationView
{
    HStack {
        Button {
            dismissValue()
        } label: {
            Text("Go Back")
                .font(.title3)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }

        NavigationLink {
            View1(toRoot: $toRoot)
        } label: {
            Text("Go Forward")
                .font(.title3)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}
.navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
}
}

struct View1: View
{
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismissValue: DismissAction
@Binding var toRoot: Bool
var body: some View
{
HStack
{
    Button {
        dismissValue()
    } label: {
        Text("Go Back")
            .font(.title3)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
    NavigationLink {
        View2(toRoot: $toRoot)
    } label: {
        Text("Go Forward")
            .font(.title3)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}
.navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
.onAppear {
    if toRoot {
        dismissValue()
    }
}
}
}

struct View2: View
{
@Binding var toRoot: Bool
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismissValue: DismissAction

var body: some View
{
HStack
{
    Button {
        toRoot = true
        dismissValue()
    } label: {
        Text("Go Back")
            .font(.title3)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
.navigationTitle(String(describing: Self.self))
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, my actual use case is different therefore I've used the binding to pass the and tried to dismiss view2 through binding. Basically, the flow goes Root -> View1 -> View2 -> View 3, and I want to go back from View3 to View1. For this purpose I will pass the binding from View1 to View2 and then to View3 and then dismiss it from there. But the problem still persists it is not working for this case.

Comment: Passing binding from
Root to View1 then View2 and making isActive false from View2 makes it pop to Root
whereas, passing binding from
View1 to View2 then View3, and making isActive false from View3 does not pops it back to View1.

Can anyone explain this behaviour ??

Comment: Based on your new comment, it seems like it's a bit different from your original post, but it is fine. I remade you another code. Please check the new edited code. You can now navigate back from view2 or view3 to your root.

Comment: Also, your original code did not work because you never pass any respond back to the root view since your root view was the one who displayed the view1.